# regular expression for alphabetic that handel before and after non alphabetics

Tags: javascript, regex

guys i need regular expression that replace alphabetic characters that have befor and after non alphabetic characters.
for example:

```
var Name = "joe";
var Time = "10:30";
var Date = "24-03-2014";
var before = "hey N how are you? iam waiting you at {T} on /D/";
var after = before.replace("N", Name);
after = after.replace("T", Time);
after = after.replace("D", Date);
// -->Output = hey joe how are you? iam waiting you at {10:30} on /24-03-2014/";
```

Knowing that the characters that is in the formatString is known by me.

Comment: What, precisely, should the eventual output be? Do you want to keep the `{`, `}` and `/` characters?

Comment: yes i want to keep all non-alphabetic characters replace only the character itself ... for example:
hey N how are you? iam waiting you at {T} 
it should become: hey joe how are you? iam waiting you at {10:30}

Comment: Word boundry construct `\b` does not handle `Not-Alpha` before/after `Alpha`. Should be `([^a-zA-Z]|^)([a-zA-Z])(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
after = before.replace(/\bN\b/, Name).replace(/\bT\b/, Time).replace(/\bD\b/, Date);
```

Comment: I agree this is a good solution, but it conflicts with @HaidarHaidar's own comments under my answer, where I suggest the same exact thing: "but if it has a numeric before and after???"

Comment: It's right, obviously, but why the doubly redundant call to `replace()`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var after = before.replace(/\b[NTD]\b/g, function(a){
   switch (a){
        case 'N':
            return Name;
            break;
        case 'D':
            return Date;
            break;
        case 'T':
            return Time;
            break;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s2B2m/).

Updated the above to use an object:

```
var details = {
        'N' : "joe",
        'T' : "10:30",
        'D' : "24-03-2014"
    },
    before = "hey N how are you? iam waiting you at {T} on /D/";

var after = before.replace(/\b[NTD]\b/g, function(a){
    return details[a] || a;
});

alert(after);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s2B2m/1/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`switch (){…}` control statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following replacements:

Find what: `\bN\b`  Replace with: Value of `Name` variable

Find what: `{T}`  Replace with: `{[VALUE_OF_Time_VARIABLE]}`

Find what: `/D/`  Replace with: `/[VALUE_OF_Date_VARIABLE]/`

You might also consider an automated [template solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20template%20engine).

Comment: good solution but the problem is that i don't know the characters and what i write is an example i only knows the alphabetics but i don't know the none-alphabetics

Comment: Then simply do a whole-word replacement for each of them, as in `\bN\b`, `\bT\b`, `\bD\b`, as I do with `Name` in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying that instead of `/D/` for example, it could be `9D9`?

Comment: +1 For the same answer the OP says he didn't want, then accepted 4 minutes later. la,la,la...

Answer (score 0):

You can build a *RegExp* from a *String* using `new RegExp(pattern, flags)`, so you can write a function like this

```
function swap(haystack, needle, replacement) {
    needle = new RegExp('\\b' + needle + '\\b', 'g');
    return haystack.replace(needle, replacement);
}

swap(
    'Meet me at {T}',
    'T',
    '18:30'
); // "Meet me at {18:30}"
```

Comment: (Duplicating this comment from anubhava's answer:) I agree this is a good solution, but it conflicts with @HaidarHaidar's own comments under my answer, where I suggest the same exact thing: "but if it has a numeric before and after???"

Comment: @HaidarHaidar: you can only accept one answer, and while you're allowed to choose as you please, try and work out which answer is most useful to you before accepting that answer; otherwise it begins to feel a little capricious.

Comment: It's like a big green checkmark strobe light in this question. Not to mention the up-down-vote numbers moving all over the place and back again. :(

Comment: @aliteralmind: well, it's not *that* strobing, it hasn't lit up my, obviously-superlative, answer yet..! :p

Comment: @DavidThomas I like your answer but I don't get why you used `switch` instead of an _Object_

Comment: First: you realise I was joking, right? I'm really not that conceited (I promise). That said, you're right: I was going to, but then I opted to keep it simple (given the OP's apparent inexperience). I might add it in, though, just for completist.

Comment: @DavidThomas: No offense taken. This is the fun-house-mirrors question of the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template engine. One good example is Mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Check this code:

```
var view = {
    user: "Joe",
    time: "20:00",    
    date: "01/01/2014"
}

var template = "hey {{user}} how are you? iam waiting you at {{time}} on {{date}}";

var output = Mustache.render(template, view);
```

Fiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/sYWfM/

Answer (score 0):

`(?!\s+\/)D(?<!\/\s)`  will fetch the D from /D/ with whitespace before and after

`(?!\s+{)T(?<!}\s)` will fetch the T from {T} with whitespace before and after

`(?!\s+)N(?<!\s)` will fetch an N with whitespace before and after

Comment: The assertions are misplaced here because there is no variable construct. Example `(?!X)A(?<!Z)` 'A' can never be 'X' or 'Z', the regex will always pass and is identical to the regex `A`

Comment: Assertions are evaluated at the position in the expression where they reside. Lookaheads look forward, so `(?=U)R` says 'on the left side of R looking right, is that char equal to U, if so, match R'. and it will never match R because  U does not equal R. Also, not sure if JavaScript supports lookbehind assertions.